# Checking for the status of a job on the webserver R

Tags: r, wait

I am executing the getURL command to check the status of a task on the server using this function below.

```
getURL(content(t2)$statusURL)
```

The status could be either "Processing" when the task is in process or "Completed_Successfully" when the task is completed.

Only if the task status is "Completed_Successfully" the following code below should be executed

```
  getURL(content(t2)$ouptputURL)
```

If the task status is still in "Processing" the code should wait until it changes to "Completed_Successfully"

Need help writing this logic in R ?

Comment: How long should it wait until it terminates as not successful?

Comment: @RichardScriven wait until the status of getURL(content(t2)$statusURL) = "Completed_Sucessfully"

Comment: So all day if it takes all day?  That's really what I meant

Comment: @RichardScriven you are right I did not think about that, what if it takes all day ? what is the right thing to do ?

Comment: Probably plan for it to terminate at some point if it hasn't yet turned successful

Comment: @RichardScriven How about ..say check for 1 hour , if the status still shows Processing then show a message saying , task taking too long check back later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a few years ago. I decided to ask the Windows Task Manager (yes, I have sinned) to run a specific script on a regular basis. Your script could be along the lines of

```
isok <- FALSE
i <- 1
while (isok == FALSE) {
  record.start <- Sys.time()
  message("Checking if job done")
  Sys.sleep(i)
  record.end <- Sys.time()
  see.difference <- record.end - record.start
  message(paste("Waiting time:", round(see.difference)))
  if (see.difference >= 5) {
    isok <- TRUE
    message("Job completed")
  }
  i <- i + 1
}

Checking if job done
Waiting time: 1
Checking if job done
Waiting time: 2
Checking if job done
Waiting time: 3
Checking if job done
Waiting time: 4
Checking if job done
Waiting time: 5
Job completed
```

Comment: I will give you an online Beer, :) this logic worked perfect.